# Extracting all records using a conditional SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server, conditional-operator

I have a long database of observations for individuals. There are multiple observations for each individual, all assigned different medcodeid's.

I want to extract all records of individuals with certain medcodeid's assigned, but only if they at some point have had a smaller list of specific codes assigned.

This is an example of what I start with:

[long dataset, multiple observations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyj8D.png)

and this is the records I'd like to extract:

[multiple observations, but patients 3 and 5 are not extracted, as they never had a medcode 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8OsW.png)

Would this be an additional WHERE clause? I am struggling as this will then only extract the second AND medcodeid list. But I want it to extract all, if the individual has had one of these certain fewer codes at some point. I hope that makes some sense. I am unfamiliar with IF command? And cannot see how CASE WHEN would work either.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please show some sample data and desired results. Word problems usually make a lot more sense to the writer than the reader.

Comment: Logically speaking, the first group logic is irrelevant since it is simply a superset of the <5 codes and date range> and anything not in that <5 codes and date range> logic will be ignored. But it is not clear what you goal is. Also, using year differences as a substitute for age is very imprecise - be sure you understand that with respect to your goal.

Comment: @AaronBertrand have added now, thank you for the advice.

Comment: @SMor yes completely understand the first is irrelevant when adding the second just not sure how to get around. Thanks for the advice, have added sample data and desired result to help explain my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely don't want to filter out all the rows so you're right that an additional condition won't help with that. And `where` only lets you look at the current row and you're trying to make a decision based all the rows belonging to the patient.

This query just uses a table expression and an analytic `count()` that tags each row with the number of matches as it lets you look outside the current row just like you need.

```
-- my additions to your query are in lowercase
with data as (
    SELECT obs.patid, yob, obsdate, medcodeid,
        count(case when medcodeid IN (<list of mandatory codes>) then 1 end)
            over (partition by obs.patid) as medcode_count
    -- assuming the relationship looks something like this
    from obs inner join medcode on medcode.patid = obs.patid
    WHERE medcodeid IN (<list of codes>)
       AND obsdate BETWEEN '2004-12-31' AND GETDATE()
       AND patienttypeid = 3 AND acceptable = 1 AND gender = 2
       AND YEAR(obsdate) - yob > 15 AND YEAR(obsdate) - yob < 45
)
select * from data where medcode_count > 0;
```

At first I thought you were requiring that at least five of the codes from the full set were found. Now that you've edited the question I believe that you want to require that at least one code from a smaller subset is present. Either way this approach will work.

Comment: Thanks very much that is very helpful. Please can I ask an additional question in your first unedited answer, as to how a better age can be calculated? I realise using yob is imprecise, but my dataset does not have a more specific dob?

Comment: @Katie I realized that after the fact. If you don't have more than yob then what can you do? Normally you would account for whether the birthday has already occurred this year but your can't without a specific date.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're asking, I think what you need is an additional `WHERE` clause with a subquery. This could be done with and EXIST or a join but I find an IN query to be easier to work with.

You left the FROM out of your query so I had to guess at it but try this:

```
SELECT
    obs.patid, 
    yob, 
    obsdate, 
    medcodeid
FROM
    obs
WHERE
    medcodeid IN (list of 20 codes)
    AND (obsdate BETWEEN '2004-12-31' AND GETDATE())
    AND patienttypeid = 3 
    AND acceptable = 1 
    AND gender = 2 
    AND ((YEAR(obsdate))-yob) > 15 
    AND ((YEAR(obsdate)) - yob) < 45
    AND obs.patid IN (
                        SELECT
                            obs.patid
                        FROM
                            obs
                        WHERE
                            medcodeid IN (5 of the 20 codes)
                    );
```